# Compiling and running the metal examples

Tags: ios, xcode6, metal

It has been a while since I have used XCode, but since Apple revieled XCode 6 and the new Metal API I had to check it out.

They have released examples, e.g. a converted version of their Basic3D example. I am having problems making them compile and run, though. I had to add paths the Quatz and Metal frameworks for compilation and linking to work - thought that should have worked out of the box with build-in libraries?

Also the metal shader compilation step fails, it can not find the metal compiler. Where in XCode is that path setup?

If I ignore the shader compilation step I get an error that the application will not run on any of the simulators. Can metal based 3D applications only run on actual hardware and not in simulator mode?

Comment: Can "someone with 1500 reputation" create the metal tag?

Comment: @tea done, use metal-framework

Comment: Note that xcode 6 messes with the framework paths, you can try deleting the "Frameworks search path" setting as even if you delete that it still finds it and compiles it. And yes, no x86 support as of this beta, PS: will crash on iOS7 devices, no idea how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run metal on simulator but you can use this workaround so that it will still compile as long as you have a fallback for the code.

http://medium.com/@jscampbell/bare-metal-working-with-metal-and-the-simulator-70e085e3a45

Comment: This is no longer true with Xcode 11! Metal works in simulators from iOS 13/tvOS13.

Answer (score 6):

According to a staff on Apple dev forums, Metal does not run in the simulator.

See: https://devforums.apple.com/message/971605#971605

If you look at other samples/app templates there is no need to explicitly link any framework, indeed everything runs out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I started with the hello triangle example they give you to download. It contains all the platform #if's you need to know about. I recommend you get that project and take a look.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/hello_triangle

```
#if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
#error No simulator support for Metal API.  Must build for a device
#endif
```