# Error while compiling parse for iOS: objc-class-ref in ParseTwitterUtils(PF_OAuthCore.o)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parsing, twitter

I just implemented Parse for iOS, but when I try to compile it I get this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFBase64Encoder", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ParseTwitterUtils(PF_OAuthCore.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've checked the frameworks imported in my App, they seem to be all.
How I Can resolve this problem? 
-Thanks in advance.

I've fixed this error by importing correctly the parse framework, but I got 3 new errors:

> 'Metal/MTLPixelFormat.h' file not found Could not build module UIKit
>   Could not build module QuartzCore

Comment: Looks like you're missing the Parse framework... Did you add ParseTwitterUtils manually or using cocoapods ?

Comment: yes, I checked everything

Comment: You didn't answer my question :-)

Comment: Oh sorry, I add it manually

Comment: Well you need to add the Parse framework too then... Check out the quick start guide if you want to know which frameworks you should add.

Comment: I fixed it by adding that framework, but now I get 3 new errors - update

Comment: I've never used Metal. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046125/compiling-and-running-the-metal-examples/24054184#24054184

Comment: This app is going mad... I'll try to re-made it from 0. Everytime I get new errors

Comment: Try using cocoapods, you will save a lot of hair.

Comment: YY thank you so much, and sorry if you wasted time.